# How to update 2 values with 1 input in react form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I have a form in react with couple of fields. 2 of those should be connected... If you enter 1, the other should be updated accordingly, but I can't get the hang of it. Whatever I try, handleChange updates only 1...

```
    const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: "",
    nameEng: "",
    type: "",
    priceKN: "",
    priceEUR: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setForm({ ...form, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

...
      <input
        type="number"
        name="priceKN"
        value={form.priceKN}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="priceEUR"
        value={form.priceEUR}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
```

So, when you enter for example 1st value, 2nd should be calculated (priceKN / 7.54) and vice versa, and shown in the form, but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function (`getValues` in the example) that parses the input, and creates an object that you can spread on the current form values:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const getValues = ({ name, value, valueAsNumber }) => {
  switch(name) {
    case 'priceKN':
      return { 
        priceKN: valueAsNumber, 
        priceEUR: valueAsNumber * 0.13
      };
    case 'priceEUR':
      return { 
        priceKN: valueAsNumber *  7.53, 
        priceEUR: valueAsNumber
      };
    default:
      return { [name]: value };
  }
}

const Demo = () => {    
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: "",
    nameEng: "",
    type: "",
    priceKN: 0,
    priceEUR: 0,
  });

  const handleChange = event => {
    setForm(values => ({ 
      ...values, 
      ...getValues(event.target)
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="priceKN"
        value={form.priceKN}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="priceEUR"
        value={form.priceEUR}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

And the same idea with `useReducer` - the `dispatch` function accepts the event object, and the reducer destructures the event's target object, and creates the new state:

```js
const { useReducer } = React;

const reducer = (
  state, 
  { target: { name, value, valueAsNumber } } 
) => {
  switch(name) {
    case 'priceKN':
      return {
        ...state,
        priceKN: valueAsNumber, 
        priceEUR: valueAsNumber * 0.13
      };
    case 'priceEUR':
      return { 
        ...state,
        priceKN: valueAsNumber *  7.53, 
        priceEUR: valueAsNumber
      };
    default:
      return { ...state, [name]: value };
  }
}

const initialValue = {
  name: "",
  nameEng: "",
  type: "",
  priceKN: 0,
  priceEUR: 0,
};

const Demo = () => {    
  const [form, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialValue);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="priceKN"
        value={form.priceKN}
        onChange={dispatch}
      ></input>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="priceEUR"
        value={form.priceEUR}
        onChange={dispatch}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parego, it happen because you update the fields in dynamically way. you need to do this way:

```
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: "",
    nameEng: "",
    type: "",
    priceKN: "",
    priceEUR: "",
  });
  const specials = ['priceKN',]

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    if(event.target.name == 'priceKN' || event.target.name == 'priceEUR')
        setForm({ ...form, priceKN: event.target.value,priceEUR: event.target.value});
    else
        setForm({ ...form, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

...
      <input
        type="number"
        name="priceKN"
        value={form.priceKN}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="priceEUR"
        value={form.priceEUR}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
```